# What does this networking ICON mean | need to restore internet connection

Tags: networking

[image: what is this networking icon]

It looks like a shield with a keyhole.  This is on Ubuntu 20.04

How come it says Wired Connected but there is still no internet connection from the wired connection on this pc?  the pc is wired directly to the router.  other PCs on the router have internet connection.

Reinstalling network-manager does not fix the problem.

Comment: That particular icon does not appear [in the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/status-icons.html.en). Does your installation have a custom firewall (not UFW) or special VPN in place?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the icon means it is connected.  The reason why there was no internet was because of some router config settings that needed to be fixed, in this case the lan connections.